# Как создать файл и недостающие папки у него по пути

Tags: c++, файлы, c++17

1. Имеется путь /home/igor/hj/fg/df/file.zzz
2. Есть папки /home/igor
3. Нужно создать пустой файл с папками по пути из п.1
4. Использовать можно только функции из C++17 (в том числе и filesystem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `create_directory` из `<filesystem>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::path path{ "/home/igor/hj/fg/df" }; //Путь
    path /= "file.zzz"; //Файл
    fs::create_directories("/home/igor/hj/fg/df");
    fs::create_directory("/home/igor/hj/fg/df1");
    std::ofstream ofs(path);
    ofs << "Текст в файле\n"; 
    ofs.close();

}
```

для создания каталога или вложенных каталогов fs::create_directories

для создания каталога  fs::create_directory

Answer (score 2):

Создать недостающие папки можно так:

```
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
fs::path p = "/home/igor/hj/fg/df/file.zzz";
fs::create_directories(p.parent_path());
```

Как создать сам файл, думаю, понятно (в С++17 для этого никаких новых средств не добавили).